Scroll reveal text animation
I'm working on a webpage where I want text to behave in a specific way when it overflows its container: instead of breaking in the middle of a word, the entire word should move to the next line.
Here's what I've done so far:
I added the following CSS properties to control word breaking:
word-break: keep-all;
overflow-wrap: normal;
word-wrap: break-word;
-webkit-hyphens: auto;
hyphens: auto;

Here's the full snippet of my code, including JavaScript for animation and the HTML structure:


class Lenis {
  constructor(options) {
    this.options = options;
    this.currentScroll = 0;
  }

  raf(time) {
    // Dummy implementation for smooth scroll effect
    this.currentScroll += (window.scrollY - this.currentScroll) * this.options.easing(0.1);
  }

  destroy() {
    // Clean-up if necessary
  }
}

function splitText(element) {
  const text = element.textContent;
  element.textContent = "";
  const wrapper = document.createElement("div");
  wrapper.style.display = "inline-block";
  wrapper.style.width = "100%";

  const spans = [...text].map((char) => {
    const span = document.createElement("span");
    span.textContent = char === " " ? "\u00A0" : char;
    span.style.display = "inline-block";
    wrapper.appendChild(span);
    return span;
  });

  element.appendChild(wrapper);
  return spans;
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  // Initialize Lenis for smooth scrolling
  const lenis = new Lenis({
    duration: 1.2,
    easing: (t) => Math.min(1, 1.001 - Math.pow(2, -10 * t)),
    direction: "vertical",
    gestureDirection: "vertical",
    smooth: true,
    smoothTouch: false,
    touchMultiplier: 2,
  });

  function raf(time) {
    lenis.raf(time);
    requestAnimationFrame(raf);
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(raf);

  window.addEventListener("unload", () => lenis.destroy());

  // Reveal text animation
  const revealElements = document.querySelectorAll(".reveal-type");

  revealElements.forEach((element) => {
    const chars = splitText(element);
    const bgColor = element.dataset.bgColor;
    const fgColor = element.dataset.fgColor;

    chars.forEach((char) => {
      char.style.color = bgColor;
    });

    const animateOnScroll = () => {
      const rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
      const windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
      const elementHeight = rect.height;

      const visibleHeight = windowHeight - rect.top;
      const progressLength = elementHeight * 1.2;

      if (visibleHeight <= 0) return;

      let progress = visibleHeight / progressLength;
      progress = Math.max(0, Math.min(1, progress));

      const charsToColor = Math.floor(progress * chars.length);

      chars.forEach((char, index) => {
        if (index < charsToColor) {
          char.style.color = fgColor;
        } else {
          char.style.color = bgColor;
        }
      });
    };

    animateOnScroll();
    window.addEventListener("scroll", animateOnScroll);

    window.addEventListener("unload", () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", animateOnScroll);
    });
  });
});
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
  background: rgb(5, 4, 4);
}

section {
  min-height: auto;
  margin: 2rem auto;
  padding: 2rem clamp(1rem, 5vw, 4rem);
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
section p {
  font-size: clamp(1.2rem, 5vw, 9rem);
  word-break: keep-all;
  overflow-wrap: normal;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
          hyphens: auto;
}
section:nth-of-type(1) {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
section:nth-of-type(1) img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
     object-fit: cover;
}
section:nth-of-type(2) {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transform: translateX(0);
}/*# sourceMappingURL=main.css.map */
  <section>
    <img src="example" alt="Thumbnail">
  </section>
  <section>
    <p 
      class="reveal-type" 
      data-bg-color="#232323" 
      data-fg-color="white"
    >
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
  </section>
  <section></section>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lenis@1.0.0/dist/lenis.min.js"></script>



As you can see, i already add
      word-break: keep-all;
  overflow-wrap: normal;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
          hyphens: auto;

The Problem
Despite adding these CSS properties, the words are still breaking in the middle and wrapping to the next line. I expected the whole word to move to the next line if it doesn't fit
What I Tried
1. Using word-break: keep-all, which, as I understand, should prevent breaking words in the middle.
2. Combining it with overflow-wrap: normal and word-wrap: break-word, thinking it would work for all browsers.
3. Adding hyphens: auto to handle hyphenation gracefully.
However, the behavior is still not what I expect. Words keep breaking mid-word.
My Environment
Browser: Arc or edge
Tools: React 19.0.0

Your javascript wraps each letter in <span> therefore there's no words, only letters, and word-wrap and all that jazz has no effect.

I see it now, thank you so much for your respond @Kosh

A different idea using only CSS (for the future as the support is still not good)


body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
  background: rgb(5, 4, 4);
}

section {
  margin-top: 100vh;
  padding: 2rem clamp(1rem, 5vw, 4rem);
}

section p {
  font-size: clamp(1.2rem, 5vw, 9rem);
}

.reveal-type span {
  background: conic-gradient(#fff 0 0) left no-repeat #232323;
  background-size: 0% 100%;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
          background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  color: transparent;
  animation: show linear forwards;
  animation-timeline: view(block);
  animation-range:  entry 10% entry-crossing 110%;
}

@keyframes show {
  to {
    background-size: 100% 100%;
  }
}
<section>
  <p class="reveal-type">
   <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</span>
  </p>
</section>




This is not possible with HTML and Css. It won't work because each alphabet in a word is independent container or div or span due to which browser will never understand that group of those container is a word.
for example :


<!-- Browsers understand that 'Hello' and 'there' is a word individually so you can use css properties on it. -->
<span>Hello there</span>

<!-- Browser don't knows that this multiple random span makes words. So browser would take each alphabet as word or group of something -->
<span>H</span>
<span>e</span>
<span>l</span>
<span>l</span>
<span>o</span>
<span>&nbsp;</span>
<span>t</span>
<span>h</span>
<span>e</span>
<span>r</span>
<span>e</span>



Now I will show you how css are applicable to both .


<!-- As browser knows that 'Hello' and 'there' is a word so it will keep them in group. -->
<div style="width: 10px">Hello there</div>
<br>
<br>
<!-- But here browser don't knows that 'Hello' and 'there' is a word instead it thinks those are seperate contains which might contain word. -->
<div style="width: 10px">
  <span>H</span>
  <span>e</span>
  <span>l</span>
  <span>l</span>
  <span>o</span>
  <span>&nbsp;</span>
  <span>t</span>
  <span>h</span>
  <span>e</span>
  <span>r</span>
  <span>e</span>
</div>
<br>
<br>

<!-- In this example browser knows that 'Hello' is a word but don't know that 'there' is a word too. -->
<div style="width: 10px">
  <span>Hello</span>
  <span>&nbsp;</span>
  <span>t</span>
  <span>h</span>
  <span>e</span>
  <span>r</span>
  <span>e</span>
</div>



So results which you are looking for is not possible with your current format, you need to tell browser that group of letters is a word by putting them in another additional div or any other way.

Ohh, I see now! I didn’t know that, thanks for clearing it up, the issue is all fixed now. Really appreciate the time you took to explain it!

The CSS property word-break is correct, but each <span> tag creates a new container, so there are no words to break in the container.
Instead of using span to control individual characters, you may want to consider using clip-path to control revealing characters in an animation.
An alternative approach would be to render your text to a canvas and control everything in JavaScript.
